# Use data from Survey123 nested repeat in main layer in AGOL or ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, arcgis-survey123

I created a form in Survey123 Connect that requires users to create a polygon using geoshape and then requires them to add the names of all the species they see in that polygon, which I created using a nested repeat. The nested repeat allows users to add as many species as they want, which may differ from polygon to polygon.

However, when I try to look at the species data in ArcGIS Pro or AGOL, it appears that the species data is a related table, but not exactly part of the main layer. This means I can't enable smart mapping or edit the symbology based on the species data. Does anyone know how I can make the nested repeats show as part of the feature layer, either by an edit on Survey123 or in ArcGIS Pro?

I found a possible solution [in this forum](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-survey123-questions/store-nested-repeat-as-feature-or-pulldata-from/td-p/863459) but I do not know how to calculate a geopoint question from another geopoint question, nor have I succeeded in using the Join Features tool to create a Hosted Layer View with the data I need.

Comment: How do you want the repeats to show in your layer? As summary counts of each species? If you're showing this in ArcGIS Online I'd look at using an Arcade expression to calculate new fields based on the related table. [This example](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-online-blog/show-related-data-or-tables-in-pop-ups-with-arcade/ba-p/890530) is populating the popup, but the process would be the same for creating a field you can use for symbology.